# Is replacing ImageView/ImageButton (set for icons) with Textview using custom icon fonts Good practice?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview, android-icons

What are the advantages/problems when using ImageView/ImageButton with TextView using custom made icon fonts in-app layouts.

There are many online [services](https://glyphter.com/) where we can upload images and create custom fonts, so instead of keeping different density `drawable`, we only need a custom font, Is there any problem with this solution or any tweaks needed?

To apply custom fonts we can use [createFromAsset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html#createFromAsset(android.content.res.AssetManager,%20java.lang.String)) method

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "icons.ttf");
```

or use library like [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy)

NOTE: my question is about explanations/issues related to replacing ImageView/ImageButton icons with icon fonts using TextView Typeface.

Comment: Needed 4 or more votes for reopening this question, any one ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking, for a simple shape, how a Vector Drawable compares to a font glyph. That's a great question!

Comment: @rds these days many designers/developers are using the custom font option for icons/menu instead of keeping a raster drawable or vector drawable am discussing the same idea, please share with others, i need a better explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework certainly favors the use of drawable rather than a custom font.

1. vector drawable have more features, for instance, they allow animations.
2. custom fonts may have render problems on devices.
3. using Textview `contentDescription` feature will be not available, and hence will cause accessibility problems.
4. latency of loading the custom font is also a factor.
5. In the case where `background` option required, using `custom font` is not an option.
6. You have also much less control regarding the sizing and spacing when using fonts.

Comment: To extend the list: `Drawable`s can be used as background, `TextView`s not. You have also much less control regarding the sizing and spacing when using fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom icons with different text fonts by using this [link](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).

Regarding your question, It will be useful to use ImageView/ImageButton as processing time for it will be less as compared to processing custom fonts. Also including external libraries may increase your app size.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, sometimes while we use it with more that 2 to 3 image at a time so at that time it will help us to set as we want with size and all that we can do. So we can use it also.